# How to redirect files from domain to another

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have many files in domain abc.com for example abc.com/file1.pdf
and changed the domain is theres anyway to redirect the users from abc.com/file1.pdf to def.com/file1.pdf
all the files are the same names, just the domain changed

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the standard [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) works.

> any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

So:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```